# Centos 5.5 - upgrade Mysql to 5.1 and get it working

Tags: mysql, centos

I am not a server administrator but hope that one can help me.  Thanks!

I have a fresh CentOS 5.5 with VirtualMin installed.

I get this when starting MySQL:
Failed to start database :
sh: /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory

IN ADDITION, I wish to upgrade from 5.0 mysql to 5.1 mysql.  I have already used this command:

```
rpm -Uvh MySQL-shared-community-5.1.56-1.rhel5.i386.rpm
```

But in Webmin my MySQL version still shows up as mysql 5.0.77-4.el5_5.4, rather than upgrade 5.0 rpm just installs 5.1 along side it.

How do I upgrade to 5.1 and configure it to work?  Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have mysql installed, try the "--replacepkgs" argument together with the "rpm" command.

Regarding `sh: /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory`, it should be fixed once you install the newer mysql successfully.

Comment: `rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs MySQL-shared-community-5.1.56-1.rhel5.i386.rpm` produces the same undesirable result

Comment: OK. Could you tell what you get from `rpm -qa | grep -i mysql` ? Does the output contains the new version?

Comment: the output contains both versions `[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
MySQL-shared-community-5.1.56-1.rhel5
mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.4`

Comment: OK. The new version is now installed. I would suggest: 1) tell us how you start mysql 2) reboot the linux box, 3) run `set | grep -i mysql` to see what environment variable is related to mysql, because `sh: /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory` clearly states mysql is not where the your script expects.

Comment: `set | grep -i mysql` returns blank, nothing

Comment: Could you tell how you start mysql? Specifically, could you write down the output of `service mysqld start`?